# Howto disable cache in Edge on windows phone 10

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge

I have windows phone 10, but when i refresh browser css is still there the old one. How may I clear and dsiable cahning in MS EDGE?

Answer (score 0):

Settings > "Choose what to clear" button > Clear

You can also a "inPrivate" tab so the cache is cleared when you close it

Comment: thansk, clearing is quite easy. But I have still no idea how to permanently disable caching for development in Edge. Thanks